# Tensorflow reshape value error

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, valueerror

I am trying to do a reshape operation on a tensor of very large shape:

```
person.tensor = <tf.Tensor 'concat_1:0' shape=(75040, 100) dtype=float32>
```

The reshape operation is as follows:

```
tensor_reshape = tf.reshape(tf.tile(person.tensor, (1, person.tensor.shape[0])),(person.tensor.shape[0]*person.tensor.shape[0], person.tensor.shape[1]))
```

The expected shape of the output is:

```
shape(5631001600 * 100)
```

However, I am getting the following ValueError

```
Cannot reshape a tensor with 563100160000 elements to shape [1336034304,100] (133603430400 elements) for 'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [75040,7504000], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1336034304,100].
```

Am I missing any condition for reshape function?